# I keep getting an error that I can not import outside of a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
import {REST, Routes} from discord.js;
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

this is the error can someone explain to me
[Here is the code](https://gist.github.com/FRISADO1/51800b3699b5605dc0d8b1f4e84bd3db)

To make a discord bot

Comment: You should either use `require`s or `import`s, not both.